# Additional argument to process during start of app from CLI c#

Tags: c#, html

I have made a HTML parser thanks to the help of this website but I am running into a new obstacle. I have a webserver that hosts configuration files that I want parsed. Instead of loading my app and inserting the link I want to just pass on a argument to my app directly from the website, for example:

htmlparser.exe http://thisismyconfig.com/config.cfg

And I want the app to load up and run the parse function in my code. It is a .NET application and I think I need to utilize ClickOnce but not too sure. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

UPDATE***

Ok, so with the following code my app does what it should but it faces one last problem (site keeps formatting the code incorrectly):

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                MyURL = args[1];
                runtimeButton_Click(sender, e);
            }
}
```

but my URL that I feed it in the argument is:

> http://jossc/configtc.aspx?IP=201.73.128.15&m=c

What is going on?

For some reason it removes the last 4 characters: &m=c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a console app and you want to hand to it the HTTP address to a config file?

You don't need ClickOnce for that. Inside your console app, look at Environment.CommandLine to get the command line arguments passed to your app. See MSDN's [Command Line Parsing Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: No, it is not a console app. It is a Windows Form App and I have a button that opens up a FileOpen dialog, in there you past the URL and it loads that up and runs my parsing command. What I want to do now is just give it a URL at runtime like if it was a command line app. Hope that clears it up a bit

Comment: I am trying:
'            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                MyURL = arg;
                navigateWeb_Click(sender, e);

            }'

which works but it asks opens the file dialog 2 times

Comment: KPS: If all you want to do is pass the application a command-line parameter when you run it, then Judah's advice still applies, as WinForms apps can still accept command-line parameters in the same way console apps do.  It might help people to answer your question if you explain the problem more clearly and thoroughly.

Comment: Ok, so with the following code my app does what it should but it faces one last problem (site keeps formatting the code incorrectly):

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                MyURL = args[1];
                runtimeButton_Click(sender, e);
            }

but my URL that I feed it in the argument is: 
http://jossc/configtc.aspx?IP=201.73.128.15&m=c

For some reason it removes the last 4 characters: &m=c

Comment: Please check the original question for proper formatting of code.

Comment: When you pass the command line argument, are you putting the address in quotes? You should, e.g. htmlparser.exe "http://jossc/configtc.aspx?IP=201.73.128.15&m=c"